# How to I do SQL on this many tables? Details inside

Tags: sql

I have a school project that uses MS Visual Studio 2010 C#. The project is a project management software. Basically managed lots of project where allowance is given to employee depending on the shift you work on. I have total 4 table to my project and they are;

1. *Employees:* where you manage all the employees details
2. *AssignProject:* where it say which employee assigned to which project
3. *Shift:* where it say which shift the employee work on
4. *Projects:* where you manage all the project details

I want to calculate total allowance for `employee`. Eg. `EmployeeA` work `3` days on *Project A* on `3` different *Shift*. How to i do SQL on it?

Updates:
I tried the follow, it managed to get EmployeeA working days but it display the allowance catered for the project. Now, how do I filter from this code that only the shift that the employee work displayed.

```
con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager
                          .ConnectionStrings["projectshift"].ConnectionString);
da = new SqlDataAdapter(@"
        SELECT 
            Shift.date, 
            Projects.AGeneral, 
            Projects.AMorning, 
            Projects.AEvening, 
            Projects.ANight 
        FROM Projects  
        INNER JOIN Shift ON Projects.ProjectId = Shift.ProjectId 
        WHERE Shift.EmployeeId='" + Session["CurrentUser"] + "'", con);
ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds, "AssignProject");
GridView1.DataSource = ds;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: You can start by writing SQL statements. Once you've tried and it's not working, post the SQL statements here with a sample of the data and the output you want to get from that data, and we'll try and help you figure out how to fix it. We can't, however, take an entirely vague description of the data and what you want to do and magically create a solution for you. Put some effort into solving it yourself, and we'll help you figure out what's wrong if it doesn't work. Good luck.

Comment: I manage to enter the following SQL but it gave me all the allowance catered for the project and not based on what the shift of employee work on.

Comment: Please **do not** put code samples or sample data into comments - since you cannot format it, it's **extremely hard** to read it.... Instead: **update** your question by editing it to provide that additional information! Thank you.

Comment: Please don't add information in comments. Edit your question and provide it there, where you can properly format it and people can see it easily when reading your question. You've also posted no table schema, no sample data, and no sample of the output you're trying to get from that data. Please try again.

Comment: Sorry. didn't know how to to it.

Answer (score 0):

Let me first suggest that you use parameterized queries -- this is vulnerable to SQL Injection.

With that said, try something like this assuming you're using SQL Server (untested) and assuming you want the distinct days from shift.date as days worked and all the records from shift.date for shifts worked:

```
SELECT Count(DISTINCT CONVERT(varchar(10), Shift.Date, 111)) as DaysWorked, 
   COUNT(Shift.date) as ShiftsWorked,
   Projects.AGeneral, Projects.AMorning, Projects.AEvening, Projects.ANight 
FROM Projects 
   INNER JOIN Shift ON Projects.ProjectId = Shift.ProjectId 
WHERE ...
GROUP BY Projects.AGeneral, Projects.AMorning, Projects.AEvening, Projects.ANight
```

Good luck.

Comment: I tried your code. It basically didn't change much except group them together. That's not what i need. What i need is to filter out which shift employeeA work then displayed the allowance on that shift for that project